# How do I refer to a "this" class member in a function parameter?

Tags: php, function, parameters, this

I currently have a function where I'm trying to refer to the $id in the class but it doesn't work:

```
public function getCourseInfo($cid = $this->id, $all = false)
{

}
```

This is my class:

```
class Course
{
    protected $course;
    protected $id;

    public function __construct($cid)
    {
        $id = $cid;
        $this->course = $this->getCourseInfo($this->id);
    }
    public function getCourseInfo($cid = $this->id, $all = false)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I assume he is trying to set a default value for the first argument with the object's id? **shrugs**

Comment: wouldn't you just make an overloaded function that doesn't take an id ? then defaults to the object id

Comment: If only PHP supported true overloading :-( (yes, this particular example can be approximated with optional arguments, but in general my complaint stands!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone in this thread is giving correct answers but no one gave a full code sample hence I'll post my suggestion:

```
class Course
{

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_courseId;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_course;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     *
     * @param int $courseId Course ID
     * @return Course
     */
    public function __construct($courseId)
    {
        $this->_courseId = (int) $courseId;
    }

    /**
     * Get course information
     *
     * @param bool $all ...
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCourseInfo($all = false)
    {
        if ($this->_course === null) {
            // use $this->_courseId as needed
            $this->_course = ... // populate course info
        }

        return $this->_course;
    }

}
```

As you'll notice I've omitted the course id parameter from getCourseInfo() simply because it's not needed if you instantiate the class with a course id.

Secondly, I don't think you should call getCourseInfo in the constructor because the information will only be needed at a later point. Also, I added "caching" to the function so that you don't fetch data twice.

Obviously there's a high chance that I could be wrong having not seen your code but I feel this is a better structure of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't established $this->id yet. :)

wrong

```
$id = $cid;
```

right

```
$this->id = $cid;
```

You're also missing a closing curly-brace on your class.

Comment: Time to start busting out the good old var_dump()! Also, are you throwing any error messages? Can you show how you are creating the object? Need more info! :)

Comment: It's a syntax error on '$this' on the actual function. Not when I'm calling it.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing curly-brace on the class, too. Can you paste the exact error message in the comments?

Comment: Get rid of the default $cid argument ( $cid = $this->id, ) and see if it still breaks. Make sure you heed my advice in the original answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the $id first in your constructor.

```
class Course
{
    protected $course;
    protected $id;
}

public function __construct($cid)
{
    $this->id = $cid;
    $this->course = $this->getCourseInfo($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function getCourseInfo($cid = 'default', $all = false)
{
    $cid = $cid == 'default' ? $this->id : $cid;

}
```

Or you need completey change your class

```
class Course
{
    protected $course;
    protected $id;

    public function __construct($cid)
    {
        $this->id = $cid;
        $this->course = $this->getCourseInfo();
    }

    public function getCourseInfo($course_id = 0, $all = false)
    {
       $course_id = !$course_id ? $this->id : $course_id;
       //do Somthing with
       //return var;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible, as stated on the [Function arguments manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> The default value must be a constant
>   expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function
>   call.

Instead you could either simply pass in null as the default and update this within your function...

```
class Course
{
    protected $course;
    protected $id;

public function __construct($cid)
{
    $this->id = $cid;
    $this->course = $this->getCourseInfo($this->id);
}
    function getCourseInfo($cid = null, $all = false) {
        $cid = isset($cid) ? $cid : $this->id;
        ....
    }
}
```